# Issue with Speech Recognition in Android App

Tags: javascript, android

My website consist of speech to text provision(when clicking on a button, it converts voice and the converted text will be displayed in site). And this site is supported in desktop & mobile chrome only. Website is created using PHP + JS.

```
 var SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
 var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
```

I've converted **website** into an **Android app** using WebView. Here, when I click on the button, it's not working. Please help.

Comment: WebView often uses the default built-in browser instead of the browser on which you're testing. The default browser may not support SpeechRecognition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my app, all UI part is visible. So the app is chrome supportable,                                                                                                          
try {
  var SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
  var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
}
catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
  $('.no-browser-support').show();
  $('.app').hide();
}